# Ожидание доступа к таблице, LOCK TABLES?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Это упрощённое описание исполнения, но..
Есть таблица со списком товара. Необходимо по одному найти товар соответствующий некоему условию, совершить над ним операцию А и в столбце operation_done записать 'А'. После этого посчитать все товары с operation_done='A' и провести операцию B.
Проблема заключается в том, что скрипты, исполняющие операции А и В запускаются кроном и может произойти накладка.
Как сделать так, чтобы операция B "подождала" доступ к таблице, пока совершается операция А?

PDO beginTransaction() не думаю что решает проблему.

Comment: А почему считаете, что транзакция не будет выходом из ситуации?

Comment: В моем случае на каждую следующую операцию А делается SELECT....WHERE operation_done!='A'. То есть мне нужно коммитить транзакцию каждый раз и как следствие смысл транзакции пропадает

Comment: В идеале был бы такой алгоритм: 1) в скрипте А в начале локаем таблицу 2) совершаем операцию А 3) разблокируем таблицу 4) то же самое с операцией В.

Comment: UPDATE TABLE ... WHERE operation_done='A' - не выход? Или вам нужно чтобы для всех записей установилось operation_done='A' и только после этого операцию B запускать?

Comment: Да-да, только после этого операцию B запускать. Или наоборот операцию А

Comment: UPDATE TABLE... WHERE operation_done='A' не выход. Потому что это упрощенно 'А'. На самом деле там Номер заявки будет указан, который заранее не известен

Comment: А почему просто не соединить обе операции в один скрипт?

Comment: К сожалению не могу объединить в один скрипт, есть ограничения. Так было бы конечно самое логичное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Это обычная задача синхронизации работы двух потоков. Обычно решается созданием некоторой "сущности", которая доступна обоим потокам.

В вашем случае одним из вариантов будет создать дополнительную таблицу с одной записью которую будет менять процесс "А" в начале своей работы и по окончании. А процесс "В" будет проверять состояние этого "флага"

Еще можно добавить в вашу уже существующую таблицу некоторое поле статуса. Процесс "А" перед началом работы ставит в поле значение "старт" - обычным UPDATE по тому самому условию, с которым он делает выборку. При обработке записи процесс "А" пишет в это поле статус "стоп".

Процесс "В" в свою очередь проверяет есть ли в таблице поле статуса со значением "старт". Если такое поле есть - значит процесс "А" еще не закончил свою работу и процессу "В" надо подождать.

Comment: А если использовать LOCK TABLES?

Comment: @phpcoding можно и lock. Тут уже все зависит от вашей задачи. Я дал более универсальное решение. Оно будет работать если обработка процесом "А" запускается не за один раз, а несколько. И позволяет остальным скриптам работать с базой без особых проблем. В случае LOCK - у вас остановится вся остальная работа с этой базой.

Comment: Остановится работа с базой или с конткретной таблицей(ми), которая залокана?

Comment: @phpcoding блокируется таблица. Соответственно остановится работа только с таблицей. Почитайте документацию - там все написано.

Comment: @phpcoding  Так как написано в данном ответе делать нельзя. потому как поток Б может начать работу в середине между проверкой состояния флага потоком А и записью нового значения флага. _НАДО_ использовать lock table или блокировки отдельных записей (для innodb) http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/InnoDB_locking_reads.html

Comment: @Mike скрипты запускаются по крону. Можно разнести их запуск по времени так, что вероятность возникновение указанной ситуации будет сильно близка к нулю. С использованием же lock tables минусов больше чем плюсов: есть возникнут проблемы с временем исполнения и скрипт А не сможет обработать данные за один свой запуск. Если скрипт А из-за ошибки завершит работу, но при этом не обработает все данные - то блокировка снимется - а это ошибка. И т.д. и т.п. Lock это правильное и красивое решение. Но как показывает опыт реальной жизни - красиво и правильно - не значит надежно и просто.

Comment: @newman Ну так я предложил лок отдельных записей, а не всей таблицы. Кстати об аварийном завершении, автосниятие лока - это может быть не такой большой проблемой, как ваш скрипт записавший флаг "работаю" и аварийно завершившийся не сняв флаг.

Comment: @Mike, как показывает опыт в данном случае ситуация "почему-то долгое время не запускается процесс В" быстрее и проще отлаживается чем ситуация "вроде бы все работает, но неправильно"

Comment: @newman Вообще, при блокировке и работе с innodb в режиме транзакций в базе в принципе не может оказаться что то изменено, а что то нет. в случае аварийного завершения снимется не только блокировка, но и откатится вся транзакция, включая все изменения которые были сделаны. И СУБД сделает это автоматически. Так что при правильном использовании СУБД, ситуации, что в базе частично исправленные данные быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам реально надо на время операции запретить другие действия, используйте лок таблицы или именованный лок. Это как раз их предназначение.

Я рекомендую именованный лок. Так как вам надо не всю работу приостановить, а только конкретных операций. Вот пусть они и "борются" за одно имя.